# Why is "de" used here rather than "des" in this duolingo question?

Tags: grammaire, articles, de

Could someone please explain why they use the second "de" in the sentence as i would have guessed "des" instead die to the fact that the object following it is plural.

Here's the phrase in French:
Mes parents reviennent toujours de voyage avec de jolis cadeaux

The English it should translate to is:
My parents always come back from their trip with nice gifts.

My thoughts were that the "de" is being used as a partitive article for "some", and both on duolingo and other websites i says that if the object its referring to is plural (like with "jolis cadeaux) then "des" should be used. Yet i don't think its an error on suolingo's part as when i put the English sentence into Google, the French it translates it into was exactly the same as duolingo used, using "de" too.

Please can someone help & explain where I'm going wrong
Thank you